# Why doesn't my list view load instantly in Xcode-12-Beta?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list, xcode12

When using the List View in SwiftUI, it doesn´t render properly. When using the simulator, it works just fine, so I only get the behavior when using on device testing.

Has anyone else seen this and knows how to fix it?

[This is the behavior I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASxZ1.gif)

Btw I´m totally new to this, so please be nice ;)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you just need to add a `listStyle` to your list. For example

```swift
List {
   ...
}.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
```